# Clickable TextView in Android

Tags: android, textview

I'm building an Android App that has many many TextViews that I want to be clickable.
I've tried to assign the properties `android:clickable="true"` and `android:onClick="clickHandler"` to the single `TextView` and when the app fires the `clickHandler(View v)` I get the clicked item correctly through `v.getId()`.
What I don't like is to define, for every `TextView`, the properties `android:clickable` and `android:onClick` ... is there something that i can do by code to say: "all the textviews are clickable and click is handled in `clickHandler` ?"

Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

You could do something like this below - this way they all have the same handler:

```
public class sticks extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener { 
  private TextView tv1; 
  private TextView tv2;
  private TextView tv3;

  @Override 
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1); 
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2); 
    tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv3); 

    // bind listeners
    tv1.setOnTouchListener(this); 
    tv2.setOnTouchListener(this); 
    tv3.setOnTouchListener(this); 

  } 

  @Override 
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 
    // check which textview it is and do what you need to do

    // return true if you don't want it handled by any other touch/click events after this
    return true; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: is this working code or pseudocode?  couldnt get it to work as is.  but tks anyway!  UPVOTED! :)

Answer (score 15):

I used this:

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTermsConditions"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:onClick="onTermConditions"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:text="Terms and Conditions"
            android:textColor="@color/blue" />
```

Comment: In this example, android:textColorLink does nothing, unless the text contains an actual hyperlink.

Comment: also needs `android:focusable="true"` according to the linter

Answer (score 7):

Hi You Must use Both of below Code :

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reg_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_btn"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Are you now need to create an account?"
        android:textColor="#ff0000ff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        />
```

And

```
private TextView tv1;
        tv1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.reg_text);
    tv1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ProgressDialog progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Title",
                    "شکیبا باشید!");
            progressBar.setCancelable(true);
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Register.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

I use an OnClickListener, try it instead of OnTouchListener.Here is the [a description how to use them](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html).

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me:

add to strings.xml:

```
 <string name="about_us"><font fgcolor="#039BE5">\"THIS IS SPARTA! more info at" <font fgcolor="#000000"><a href="https://google.com/">google.com</a></font>
</string>
```

add to TextView:

```
android:linksClickable="true"
```

add to activity:

```
about_us.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
```

Comment: This still has the setting act for each textview, which @Cris wanted to avoid... You should elaborate a bit about movementMethod (an interesting solution)

Answer (score 0):

Hello You Must use Both of below Code :

1. Use is XML file code

   ```
   <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
    android:id="@+id/tx_demo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Demo World!" />
   ```
2. Use is JAVA file code

   ```
    txDemo = findViewById(R.id.tx_demo);
    txDemo.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Toast.makeText(this, "TextView Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });
   ```

OR
2) Use is Kotlin file code

```
 txDemo = findViewById(R.id.tx_demo)
    txDemo!!.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "TextView Click",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
    }
```