# how to use visible and invisible for a button in android

Tags: android, button, onclick, visibility

I want to make a button invisible, when i click another button then the invisible button will become visible and then perform `onClick()` actions on the visible button.

What `onClick()` actions I can use on the visible button. I used this method shown below:

```
   donebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done);
    donebutton.setOnClickListener(this);
    donebutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if(v.equals(remove))
           {
             donebutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           }
        if(v.equals(donebutton))
            {
                Intent i=new Intent(One.this,Second.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
                donebutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

      }
```

In the above method the invisible and visible propertyes are working but `onClick()` action is not working. so please tell me an answer for the above problem or tell me if there is any other method for visible and invisible on button and onclick action on that button.

and I also used this method:

```
       done.setClickable(true);
       done.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
         public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(One.this,Second.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
         }
     });
```

Comment: Have you set remove.setOnClickListener(this);

Answer (score 27, accepted):

DONT USE -

```
donebutton.setVisibility(4);
```

Instead use the static constants for this:

```
donebutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

What exactly means

```
done.setVisibility(0);
```

Isn't is supposed to be

```
donebutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: i replaced all of these but didn't perform onclick action on that button

Comment: Try to set specific clickListener for the button, something like ...
donebutton.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener(){
@Override public void onClick(...){...}});

Comment: Also check if setClickable(true)

Comment: +1 For avoid using magic numbers and sticking to consts... That's what they are there for!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
Button theButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.theButton);
theButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
theButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

phoneButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{ 
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v)
 {
  // DO STUFF
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this can help you to hide the buttons as well as show the buttons if they are hidden. You need to have three buttons in your layout file in order to follow this example.

```
Button b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
     @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (b1.isShown() && b2.isShown()) {
                            b1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            b2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        } else {
                            b1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            b2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try onTouch() instead of onClick(): [Clickable TextView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613333/clickable-textview-in-android/4613388#4613388)