# Android : Why onClick method is not working?

Tags: android, onclick, textview

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

onClick method defined in xml

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/titlemainpage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    android:text="Social To Dos"   
    android:onClick="testing" />
```

testing method used in java class is

```
public void testing(View v){

    Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    textview.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
}
```

Comment: If you're throwing an `Exception` post the log.

Comment: nothing happens after clicking textview

Comment: You want to override onClick. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613333/clickable-textview-in-android) for more info.

Comment: @ShahzadImam :  add `android:clickable="true"` for `textview`

Comment: Toas message is also not showing ?

Comment: i am using method onClick from xml.

Comment: @imrankhan:Sorry imran i had not seen ur answer.u answered b4 all...

Comment: You have to set setOnClickListener on onCreateView e.g. mBinding.llSpeedHome.setOnClickListener(this)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Add one more attribute to the textview in xml:

**android:clickable="true"**

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It was working out of the box since the day I started making my app... But suddenly today: The TextView's onClick="methodName" was not at all being called on pre-lollipop devices. Why it worked so far is a mystery now :P

Comment: Don't forget to add setOnClickListener on onCreateView too e.g. mBinding.llSpeedHome.setOnClickListener(this)

Answer (score 2):

Buttons are by default clickable but TextViews are not. Unless you explicitly setup the onClick listener at runtime textViews won't be clickable on pre-Lollipop devices.

So if you want to make a TextView clickable which is hooked with a listener in XML layout file you should use

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont forget to remove the on click listener (if you have set that programmatically inside the containing activity).

Answer (score 0):

You have to set setOnClickListener on onCreateView e.g. mBinding.llSpeedHome.setOnClickListener(this)

Answer (score -3):

I might be wrong but I think you have to implement a listener rather than using a simple function.

Check [this website](http://tseng-blog.nge-web.net/blog/2009/02/14/implementing-listeners-in-your-android-java-application/).

Comment: onClick via XML is a feature since 1.6: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-1.6.html