# Creating clickable sides in Cube

Tags: android, opengl-es, cube

I'm referring to the 3D cube example given in API demo . But how to make the side of the cube as clickable?

Comment: a) If you refer to some example please link to it. b) I don't know the example but for 3D clickable things you need to transform coordinates from screen (x, y of touchpoint) to 3d space (x,y,z) to find out where you clicked so it's usually not that simple to make 3D clickable.

Comment: I'm using normal api demo which comes along with Android SDK. Is there any example which shows, transforming coordinates from 2d space to 3d space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Elements" ([Cubes](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/kube/Cube.html), in this case) inside a `GLSurfaceView` are not clickable in the sense [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4613333/1262542). You will need to add this convenience yourself. See the answers to [this question about ray-picking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093096/implementing-ray-picking).