# How to make a TextView clickable in android

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to make text in `TextView` clickable (allow copy to clipboard) and links also clickable but without any success.

Here is my **MainActivity.xml** code:

```
android:enabled="true"
android:textIsSelectable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:longClickable="true"
android:linksClickable="true"
```

Here is the **MainActivity** Kotlin file:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4613333/12478830

Comment: You can check my answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952914/copy-text-from-textview-on-android/64222969#64222969

Answer (score 1):

just add onclicklistner to your textview.

For your reference

```
 textView.setOnClickListener((View view) -> {
          //Your code
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code so when you click on a TextView, the text will be copied to the clipboard :

```
myTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("copy", myTextView.getText().toString());
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Copied To Clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });
```

Comment: Where did you put the code? Can you share the logcat when the app crashes?

Comment: Thanks for your support, i put the code on the MainActivity.kt the android studio as changed the code to klotin  the logcat its big there is the last lines let me know if you need the whole log:

Comment: You forgot, to declare your text view before your setOnClickListener. val postCaption = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.myTextView).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/no"
     style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
 />
```